# How to return a list of objects as an IHttpActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.NET webapi and I can't find a way to return a list of objects queried by id.

This is my controller method for the GET request.
I want to return all the questions which have a specified questionnaireId passed via url.

I tried this:

```
// GET: api/Questions/5
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Question>))]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)
{
    var questions = from q in db.Questions
    where q.QuestionnaireId == questionnaireId
    select new Question()
    {
            Id = q.Id,
            ImageLink = q.ImageLink,
            QuestionnaireId = q.QuestionnaireId,
            Text = q.Text
    };
    return questions;
}
```

This is my Question class:

```
public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Questionnaire")]
        public int QuestionnaireId { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string ImageLink { get; set; }

        public virtual Questionnaire Questionnaire { get; set; }
    }
```

But on `return questions` it shows the compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<finah_backend.Models.Question>` to `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I want to get a list of questions returned in JSON queried on questionnaireId, which is passed via a url i.e. api/questions/2 ==> gives me back all the questions with questionnaireId = 2.

Comment: What is errror or did you get any exception? I think your method `GetQuestion` would not compile due to mismatching return type with what you have returned actually.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<finah_backend.Models.Question>' to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the `[ResponseType]` attribute, but that's only for generating documentation, see [MSDN: ResponseTypeAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Use this to specify the entity type returned by an action when the declared return type is HttpResponseMessage or IHttpActionResult. The ResponseType will be read by ApiExplorer when generating ApiDescription.

You can either change your return type (and remove the attribute, as it isn't required anymore as the return type documentation will be generated from the actual signature):

```
public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)
```

Or, if you want it to be async:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Question>> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)
```

Or wrap the result in an `IHttpActionResult`, which the method `Request.CreateResponse<T>()` does:

```
 return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Question>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, questions);
```

The latter is done for you if you call the `ApiController.Ok()` method:

```
return Ok(questions);
```

Comment: I changed the return type to `public Task<IEnumerable<Question>> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)` but I still get the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<finah_backend.Models.Question> to 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @Fairbreath see edit. You're mixing up syntaxes. Use `public IEnumerable<>` or `public async Task<IEnumerable<>>`.

Comment: Why would you make the method async . it doesn't await anything. These answers don't work.

Answer (score 6):

Just simply return it like this, you need to use one of the nice methods that ApiController now supplies.

This will return a status code of 200 along with your questions collection.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Question>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)
{
    var questions = from q in db.Questions
    where q.QuestionnaireId == questionnaireId
    select new Question()
    {
            Id = q.Id,
            ImageLink = q.ImageLink,
            QuestionnaireId = q.QuestionnaireId,
            Text = q.Text
    };
    return this.Ok(questions);
}
```

Comment: _"Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult` to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult>`"_. OP is missing the `async` modifier.

Comment: Yes, when trying to solve a compiler error OP is not helped with another compiler error. You also may want to point out the added `async` in your answer.

Comment: @Fairbreath .. That sounds like an entirely different question? Please ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @Fairbreath that has nothing to do with the error "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<finah_backend.Models.Question> to System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" which is what my answer solves.

Comment: Please edit your question, it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use the entity directly for providing data.
Create a DTO for your entities:

```
public class QuestionDto
{

  public int id {get; set;}
  //put here getter and setter for all other Question attributes you want to have

  public QuestionDto(Question question){
    this.id = question.id;
    ... and so on
  }
}
```

Then your GET method could look like this:

```
// GET: api/Questions/5
public List<QuestionDto> GetQuestion(int questionnaireId)
{
    IEnumerable<QuestionDto> questions = from q in db.Questions
    where q.QuestionnaireId == questionnaireId
    select new QuestionDto(q);
    return questions.toList();
}
```

I also recommend to use JSON for data transfer since it is quite ease to use with Javascript.

Comment: Oh forget this one, just wrap your Answers in a HttpResonseMessage.
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, your object to return);

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for some code similar to below:

```
public IEnumerable<Question> Get(int id)
    {
        //Create the list that you need to return here
        // I am creating a new list and adding an object below just for 
        // explaining the idea.

        var questions = new List<Question>();
        questions.Add(new Question());
        return questions;
    }
```