# Can Web API HttpPost return ICollection

Tags: json, web-services, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Newb to writing Web Services.  Am using C#/ASP.Net with WebAPI.  End goal is to receive JSON collection, and deserialize the data to database, and inform client application of any failed records, which client will log.

Can the HTTPPost return a collection of the failed rows (as serialized Json) through an IHttpActionResult or HttpResponseMessage, kind of like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<Things> t)
{
    // deserialize t and process to database

    // list of failed records
    ICollection<Thing> things= new List<Thing>();
    things.Add(...);
    things.Add(...);

    string jsonFailedRows = 
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject(things, Formatting.Indented);

    // Write the list to the response body
    HttpResponseMessage response =     
       Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonFailedRows);
    return response;
}
```

I saw this link: [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163827/how-to-return-a-list-of-objects-as-an-ihttpactionresult), which says the I can do the following, but is this correct for a Post?

"The latter is done for you if you call the ApiController.Ok() method:

```
return Ok(jsonFailedRows);
```

And lastly, is there any way of using CreatedAtRoute to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted in the linked response indeed answers this question.